# Android Navigation Component showing white screen after navigating to different screen

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using the Jet pack navigation component and facing some issues with the fragment transitions. I want to achieve navigation from ProfileFragment -> PersonalInfoFragment, when user navigate to PersonalInfoFragment it is showing blank white screen. This is happening first time on the fresh install. Once user reopen app it is working fine.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.spendlee.dev.views.fragment.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="ProfileFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >        
        <action
            android:id="@+id/navigate_profileFragment_to_personalInfoFragment"
            app:destination="@id/personalInfoFragment"/>
</fragment>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you get any findings or solution?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed this issue. Somewhere in my code, I was making UI changes on the coroutine thread and it was taking windows focus. So I wrapped that UI part into runOnUIThread and it worked.